# Laravel 4 Call to undefined method create()

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do database seed to my new database table.

ProductSeeder.php

```
class ProductSeeder extends DatabaseSeeder {

public function run()
{
    $products = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'DSLR D300S (body only)',
            'image' => 'D300S_16_85_front34l_i.jpg',
            'stock' => 'Available',
            'price'=>'5188.00'
            )
        );


    foreach ($products as $product) {
        Product::create($product);
    }
}
}
```

model/Product.php

```
class Product extends Eloquent{
}
```

However, when I run `db:seed` it says "Call to undefined method Product::create()".

How could I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When seeding your database relying on models isn't a particularly good idea, this comes to the forefront when you're trying to unit test (database test) your models through repositories.

Instead use the raw query builder (with the fluent interface).

```
DB::table('products')->insert(array(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to seed in Laravel is to use 'DB::table()':

```
class ProductSeeder extends DatabaseSeeder {

    public function run()
    {

        $products = array(
                            array(
                                'name' => 'DSLR D300S (body only)',
                                'image' => 'D300S_16_85_front34l_i.jpg',
                                'stock' => 'Available',
                                'price'=>'5188.00'
                                )
                        );

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            DB::table('products')->insert($products);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot say if its your problem, but i was getting this error due to a typo in my seeder file

Instead of

```
Product::create($product);
```

I had

```
// note only one semicolon
Product:create($product);
```

This it at any rate definately causes the same error !

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function create()
```

So i would definately recommend you check your code again

Also i was only extendting Seeder and not DatabaseSeeder
So also try

```
class ProductSeeder extends Seeder {
```

Answer (score -1):

Class Product needs to have a method Create.

```
class Product extends Eloquent{

    public function create($product)
    {
        // Do something
    }

}
```